# How to get select value for AJAX using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html-select

I have 2 HTML drop down menus.

```
<div class="bar-option">
    <label>Filter:</label>
    <form>
        <select name="retreat_locations" onchange="filterRetreats(this.value, 'count(reviews.retreat_id)')">
            <option value="alllocations" selected="selected">All Locations</option>
            <?php foreach ($this->locations as $location) {?>
            <option value="<?=htmlentities($location->retreat_location);?>">
                <?=htmlentities($location->retreat_location);?> </option>
            <?php }?>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="bar-option">
    <label>Sort by:</label>
    <select onchange="filterRetreats('alllocations', this.value)">
        <option selected='selected' value='retreat_number_of_reviews'>Popularity</option>
        <option value='retreat_founded_in'>Age</option>
        <option value='total_review_cost'>Cost</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As you can see from the above, the second select uses the static value 'alllocations' as the first parameter for the onchange function.

How can I replace this static value with the selected option of the first dropdown (retreat_locations)?

I tried retreat_locations.value but it didn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
document.querySelector('[name=retreat_locations]').value
```

Your code will become:

```
filterRetreats(document.querySelector('[name=retreat_locations]').value, this.value)
```

Demo:

```js
function filterRetreats(value1, value2) {
  console.log(value1, value2);
}
```

```html
<div class="bar-option">
                    <label>Filter:</label>
                    <form>
                        <select name="retreat_locations" onchange="filterRetreats(this.value, 'count(reviews.retreat_id)')">
                            <option value="alllocations" selected="selected">All Locations</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                        </select>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="bar-option">
                    <label>Sort by:</label>
                    <select onchange="filterRetreats(document.querySelector('[name=retreat_locations]').value, this.value)">
                        <option selected='selected' value='retreat_number_of_reviews'>Popularity</option>
                        <option value='retreat_founded_in'>Age</option>
                        <option value='total_review_cost'>Cost</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
```

Other -old school- option is to add an `id` tag to the first select, e.g. `id="retreat_locations"` and use `document.getElementById('retreat_locations').value`.